# Elasticsearch javascript search field in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch

This comes directly from the [elasticsearch documentation.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-search)

```
client.search({
  index: 'myindex',
  body: {
    query: {
      match: {
        title: 'test'
      }
    }
  }
}, function (error, response) {
  // ...
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is the same but search for multiple titles.

Sort of the equivallent of `if title in ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']`

However `title: ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']` gives an error as a query string.

There was another suggestion to use filter but it seems to not have any effect. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to append all the title values into your query string as it will be analyzed and thus the `title` field will be matched against each token.

```
client.search({
  index: 'myindex',
  body: {
    query: {
      match: {
        title: 'title1 title2 title3'
      }
    }
  }
}, function (error, response) {
  // ...
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you search for not-analyzed values, you should prefer a `terms` query:

```
client.search({
  index: 'myindex',
  body: {
    query: {
      terms: {
        title: ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']
      }
    }
  }
}, function (error, response) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I am searching on non-analysed fields (IDs) and this method gives back 0 hits.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to combine `terms` with `match` (analysed and non-analysed search)? Something like `title: ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']` AND `author: 'myAuthor'`?

Comment: Yes, though, this would better fit in a different question so as not to mix different concepts together.